# Pandas: rank groupby and then compute bins qcut

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with multiple scores and multiple dates. My goal is to bin  each day into equal sized buckets (let's say 5 buckets) based on whatever score I choose. The problem is that some scores have an abundance of ties and therefore I need to first compute rank to introduce a tie-breaker criteria and then the `qcut` can be applied.

The simple solution is to create a field for the rank and then do `groupby('date')['rank'].transform(pd.qcut)`. However, since efficiency is key, this implies doing two expensive groupbys and I was wondering if it is possible to "chain" the two operations into one sweep.

This is the closest I got; my goal is to create 5 buckets but the qcut seems to be wrong since it is asking me to provide hundreds of labels

```
 df_main.groupby('date')['score'].\
         apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x.rank(method='first'),
                                 5,
                                 duplicates='drop',
                                 labels=lbls)
               )
```

Thanks

Comment: Apply() is quite slow - it may be quicker to do groupby and eat it that way,,,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472327/slow-performance-of-pandas-groupby-apply

Comment: thank you for the feedback. Recall that my baseline scenario is to do 2 groupbys and my goal is doing just one

Comment: if you order your dataframe according to score, then take the 20% within each group? or am i missing something important?

Comment: the ordering might be expensive as well, no? it's a good idea but sadly it won't work for what I need. I oversimplified for clarity sake, but I need to keep all the 5 groups and compare them, so I can't just keep the top n rows