# pandas rolling apply function has slow performance

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-rolling

The source code in question is

```
import numpy as np
dd=lambda x: np.nanmax(1.0 - x / np.fmax.accumulate(x))
df.rolling(window=period, min_periods=1).apply(dd)
```

It takes an extremely long time to execute the above 2 lines of code.
It is with latest pandas version(1.4.0).
The dataframe has 3000 rows and 2000 columns only.

Same code with previous pandas version(0.23.x) provides result much faster.

I've tried with other suggessions and questions like [Slow performance of pandas groupby/apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472327/slow-performance-of-pandas-groupby-apply) but are of not much help.

*period* is a int variable with value 250.

Comment: Since it seems to be working differently in an older pandas version, have you already posted this as an issue on [their github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)?

Comment: @FlyingTeller. Not yet.
I'm not even aware of what working difference are you referring to.

Comment: Referring to your sentence `Same code with previous pandas version(0.23.x) provides result much faster.`. This sounds to me like you are not doing anything wrong but that the new pandas version introduced changes that make it slower

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller I've raised the issue on the link provided.

Comment: what means `"much faster"`? Did you measure time? You could show time results.

Answer (score 1):

These are not a solution, at most workarounds for simple cases like the example function. But it confirms the suspicion that the processing speed of `df.rolling.apply` is anything but optimal.

Using a much smaller dataset for obvious reasons

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(200,100)
)
period = 10
res = [0,0]
```

Running time with `pandas` v1.3.5

```
%%timeit -n1 -r1
dd=lambda x: np.nanmax(1.0 - x / np.fmax.accumulate(x))
res[0] = df.rolling(window=period, min_periods=1).apply(dd)
# 1 loop, best of 1: 8.72 s per loop
```

Against a `numpy` implementation

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as window
```

```
%%timeit
x = window(np.vstack([np.full((period-1,df.shape[1]), np.nan),df.to_numpy()]), period, axis=0)
res[1] = np.nanmax(1.0 - x / np.fmax.accumulate(x, axis=-1), axis=-1)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 3.39 ms per loop
```

```
np.testing.assert_allclose(res[0], res[1])
```

`8.72*1000 / 3.39 = 2572.27` x speedup.

---

#### Processing columns in chunks

```
l = []
for arr in np.array_split(df.to_numpy(), 100, 1):
    x = window(np.vstack([np.full((period-1,arr.shape[1]), np.nan),arr]), period, axis=0)
    l.append(np.nanmax(1.0 - x / np.fmax.accumulate(x, axis=-1), axis=-1))
res[1] = np.hstack(l)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 9.15 s per loop for df.shape (2000,2000)
```

---

#### Using `pandas` `numba` engine

We can get even faster with `pandas` support for `numba` jitted functions. Unfortunately `numba v0.55.1` can't compile `ufunc.accumulate`. We have to write our own implementation of `np.fmax.accumulate` (no guarantees on my implementation). Please note that the first call is slower because the function needs to be compiled.

```
def dd_numba(x):
    res = np.empty_like(x)
    res[0] = x[0]
    for i in range(1, len(res)):
        if res[i-1] > x[i] or np.isnan(x[i]):
            res[i] = res[i-1]
        else:
            res[i] = x[i]
    return np.nanmax(1.0 - x / res)
```

```
df.rolling(window=period, min_periods=1).apply(dd_numba, engine='numba', raw=True)
```

We can use the familiar pandas interface and it's ~1.16x faster than my chunked `numpy` approach for `df.shape` (2000,2000).

Comment: Thanks @Michael. The workaround seems to to work fantastically well on small dataframes, however it doesn't seem to work on the dataframe size I mentioned. Error code is "numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 20.6 GiB for an array with shape (5909, 1874, 250) and data type float64".
I guess I need to segment DF into pieces to make it work.
Any suggestion..

Comment: I see, the vectorized function is trying to allocate 20 GiB.I have enough memory to process, so I didn't notice. Splitting every 100 columns should work for your example since each column can be calculated separately.

Comment: I added a solution to process columns in chunks and then combine them.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I figured out with my own vectorized solution, by taking chunk of 10 columns. Now just to tell you the performance difference. The source code mentioned in problem statement(question) is taking almost 50 minutes to get the output. 
Vectorized function using your function give the output in 40 seconds.
Thank you so much.  Only thing remains is I'm yet to understand the workaround you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/) library. With its help, you can parallelize the `apply` method of a sliding window. Thanks Michael Szczesny for `dd_numba` function. I considered the dataframe of the size you need

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import monotonic
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas


def dd_numba(x):
    res = np.empty_like(x)
    res[0] = x[0]
    for i in range(1, len(res)):
        if res[i - 1] > x[i] or np.isnan(x[i]):
            res[i] = res[i - 1]
        else:
            res[i] = x[i]
    return np.nanmax(1.0 - x / res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize parallel-pandas
    ParallelPandas.initialize(n_cpu=4, split_factor=1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3000, 2000))
    period = 250
    dd = lambda x: np.nanmax(1.0 - x / np.fmax.accumulate(x))

    start = monotonic()
    res = df.rolling(window=period, min_periods=1).apply(dd)
    print(f'synchronous time took: {monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')

    start = monotonic()
    res = df.rolling(window=period, min_periods=1).apply(dd, raw=True)
    print(f'with raw=True time took: {monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')

    start = monotonic()
    res = df.rolling(window=period, min_periods=1).apply(dd_numba, raw=True, engine='numba')
    print(f'numba engine time took: {monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')

    start = monotonic()
    res = df.rolling(window=period, min_periods=1).p_apply(dd, raw=True)
    print(f'parallel with raw=True time took: {monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')
    start = monotonic()
    res = df.rolling(window=period, min_periods=1).p_apply(dd_numba,  raw=True, engine='numba')
    print(f'parallel with raw=True and numba time took: {monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')
```

```
Output:
synchronous time took: 994.6 s.
with raw=True time took: 48.6 s.
numba engine time took: 9.8 s.
parallel with raw=True time took: 13.5 s.
parallel with raw=True and numba time took: 1.5 s.
```

`994/1.5 ~ 662.6` x speedup.